# how do I display a double to 2 decimal points?

Tags: flutter, dart

How I can display or keep double values to 2 decimal points?

```
textContent: 'Total Payable: ' + '€'+finalPrice.toString(),
```

I need to know how to ensure that

```
double finalPrice;
```

that `finalPrice` is always displayed to 2 decimal points. Whether it is converted to a string or not.

I've tried everything and called my MP.

```
double finalPrice = 0.00;
```

I noticed that initialising it as 0.00 seems to do something, but I need something a bit more solid.

The expected result is the client should pay for what they've purchased. The actual result is we are charging the customer a bit more than what they've purchased

Answer (score 56):

```
double d = 1.5124;
String number = d.toStringAsFixed(2); // 1.51
```

---

Even if you have

```
double d = 1.51 // number: 1.51
double d = 1.5 // number: 1.50
double d = 1 // number = 1.00
```

You can see you will always have 2 decimal places with `toStringAsFixed(2)`.

Comment: and what about if i wanna show 3.000,00 $  for 3000.00 $ it will be shown with 1000 Counts with a 1x dot , and decimal will be decided from main Count ? Thanks

Comment: @Koek In that case, you need `NumberFormat` from the [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

Comment: That is not true. For instance: `12.499166666666667.toStringAsFixed(2)` gives `12.50` - a rounded result